# Reg Expression Javascript for Millions with limit

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I am looking to create a regular expression in javascript that does the following:

1. Allows for 1 or more numbers
2. Then has an optional period (".")
3. Then has an optional number of digits up to 6

The context is that i need people to enter in numeric values in the millions and i want them to at least include a 0 if they are entering thousands... so they could enter the following:

1 (would be one million)
0.725 (would be 725k)
10.5 (would be 10M 500K)

I also need to ensure that the value doesn't reach over 725.00 (or 725 million).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to check something is a number, and in a given range.  No need for a regex for that.

Comment: Try `parseFloat()` and check the output is valid with `isNaN()`.

Comment: classic [law of the instrument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) problem. You're using the wrong tool for the job. Don't use RegEx for checking numeric boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want a number that would be multiplied by 10^6 to get the true value.

This sounds like a two-stepper; First, verify that the input string is in a format you expect (you can use a regex for this very easily). Then, parse the string into a number variable and test the actual value. The regex pattern for that would look like `"[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,6})?"`, basically matching a number with up to 3 whole digits and 6 fractional digits, the decimal place and fractional digits being optional. If it matches this pattern, then it's parsable into a number, and you can then perform a quick check that your number <= 725.

I honestly don't think it's feasible to create a single Regex that can validate a proper numeric format AND an inclusive maximum range, but here's a start:

`"^(725(\.0{1,6})|(([7][2][0-4]|[7][0-1][0-9]|[1-6][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(\.[0-9]{1,6})?)$"`

This will allow any natural whole number from zero to 724, with any fractional part up to six digits from ".000001" to ".999999". It does this in stages; it will match 720-724, or 700-719, or any three-digit number up to 699, or any two-digit number, or any one-digit number. Then, it will also match the quantity "725" explicitly, with an optional decimal point and up to 6 zeroes.

EDIT: While your comment states that you used this pattern, and it does produce the correct result, I had intended it as a "what not to do"; this pattern will be far more costly to evaluate than the first solution, just to avoid a server-side rule check. And you will have to perform a server-side validation anyway; anything done within the confines of the user's browser should be suspect because the user can disable JavaScript or can even use browser plug-ins like FireBug to make your HTML page behave the way he wants, instead of the way you designed it.

Comment: I was blinded by the light. The reg expression worked and i added the control for the comparison. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like:

```
/^(?!\d{4})(?![89]\d\d)(?!7[3-9]\d)(?!72[6-9])(?!725\.0*[1-9])(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d{1,6})$/
```

which means:

- doesn't start with four digits (i.e., is less than `1000`)
- doesn't start with `8` or `9` followed by two digits (i.e., is less than `800`)
- doesn't start with `73`-`79` followed by a digit (i.e., is less than `730`)
- doesn't start with `726`-`729` (i.e., is less than `726`)
- doesn't start with `725.` followed by zero or more zeroes followed by a nonzero digit (i.e., is less than or equal to `725.00`).
- starts either with `0`, or with `1`-`9` followed by zero or more digits
- after that, optionally a decimal point followed by between one and six digits

That said, I'd actually recommend implementing the above as several separate checks, rather than cramming it all into one regex like the above. In particular, the "is less than or equal to `725.00`" check is probably better implemented using numeric comparison; and even if you do want to use a regex for that, you probably want to detect it as a separate error from `0.1asefawe` so you can give a more precise error-message.

Comment: Just looking at this regex is enough proof that it's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Indeed! Alan Perlis once wrote, "Beware of the Turing tar-pit in which everything is possible but nothing of interest is easy." Regexes aren't actually Turing-complete -- not even close -- but even so I think they prove his point. :-)

Comment: Thanks for humoring me, and your explanation was very helpful. i decided to take your recommendation and add a second validator on the field. Thanks!